# Preconfigured group

Tags: user-management

Does anyone know where to find detail description or documentation for preconfigured groups on Ubuntu 12.04?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really.

But I can find some [documentation](http://wiki.gacq.com/index.php/Debian_default_system_groups_description) about default Debian groups. Ubuntu is a Debian derivative and this close to the base deviations are rare. This info applies to Ubuntu and if Debian maintains it, it will likely continue to apply.